# How to send a mail using an alias email address using Office 365 Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I can successfully send the email using the default email account (authorized account) by leveraging the Microsoft Graph API.

Now, I would like to send the email using one of the aliases assigned to the account. When I check the sent & received email it always shows the default email in the from address. I would like to see the alias email-id in the from address.

From the Outlook client, I can both send and receive email via configured alias.

Also, I am interested in updating the 'Name' shown for the from address. Always the email account has the same name as in the Azure AD.

Sample Message:

```
{
  "Message": {
    "Subject": "Subject Goes Here",
    "Body": {
      "ContentType": "Html",
      "Content": "BODY GOES HERE"
    },
    "ToRecipients": [
      {
        "EmailAddress": {
          "Name": "receiver",
          "Address": "receiver@domain.com"
        }
      }
    ],
    "From": {
        "EmailAddress": {
          "Name": "Alias Name ",
          "Address": "sender-alias@domain.com"
        }
    },
    "attachments": []
  },
  "SaveToSentItems": true
}
```